# Bigquery - group different rows into one by visitId

Tags: google-bigquery

I got this output:

[image]

Is there a function to group these rows into one by visitId? They're in different rows because they are different events happen in different times.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use [GROUP [EACH] BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference)  syntax

```
select visitId
from [mytable]
GROUP BY visitId
```

Comment: Sending events about 'Card security Code' is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that for each event appears no more than once per row with same visitId, then you can use aggregation function FIRST, i.e.

```
SELECT visitId, FIRST(CARD_SEC_CODE), FIRST(TERMS), FIRST(CARD_TYPE), ...
FROM t
GROUP BY visitId
```